# Why is this MH370's disappearance question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic

This: [Are there any Airworthiness Directives for the Boeing 777 that might explain MH370's disappearance?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3064/14897)

It asks for speculation (the word "might") on an accident that remains a mystery. Or as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines_Flight_370) puts it:

> Cause unknown, some debris found

From the [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)...

> Accident speculation
>   "What happened to Flight 12345?" when the incident is still under investigation

... are off-topic.

[Latest review](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/close/47522) was 3x leave open and 1x close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following part of the question seems answerable to me:

> Are there currently any ADs for Boing 777s which would indicate the potential for catastrophic electronic system failures...

Unfortunately the rest of the question does seem to invite speculation. The top voted answer mainly focuses on whether an electrical failure could explain the incomplete evidence right now, which basically amounts to speculating about the incident.

Based on that I agree that the question should be closed and that editing to remove speculation is difficult as the existing answer mainly focuses on that.

Comment: "Unfortunately the top voted answer mainly focuses on whether an electrical failure could explain the incomplete evidence right now" The question body explicitly asks for that: "Are there currently any ADs for Boing 777s which would indicate the potential for catastrophic electronic system failures **that might explain MH370's transponder failure and other issues?**" The only way to answer this seems to be to explain that there aren't any electronic system failures that are consistent with the known facts of MH370. Pretty much only intentional pilot action is at this point.

Comment: As @reirab have noted, *the question does focus on MH370,* which you agree would be off-topic. Would trimming the MH370 stuff out of the question be an acceptable edit? I don't think so as it would invalidate an answer. I don't see any other option other than putting it on hold.